Does the card you pull out from the deck of many things come back?
The description of the Deck of many things sound like the card is gone forever, but I have seen people say it comes back from the deck. Which one actually happens?

As the posted answer outlines, the item description answers this rather directly. Was there something specific about it that was confusing to you?

Unless the card is the Fool or the Jester, a card can be drawn multiple times.
The item description says (emphases mine):

Once a card is drawn, it fades from existence. Unless the card is the Fool or the Jester, the card reappears in the deck, making it possible to draw the same card twice.

The bolded parts say that the card disappears (from your hand) and then it reappears in the deck, and it explicitly says that the same card can be drawn multiple times.
The exceptions, as stated in the description, are the Fool and the Jester: these cards cannot be drawn more than once.

The description you linked answers your question
The description of the Deck is quite straightforward:

Once a card is drawn, it fades from existence. Unless the card is the Fool or the Jester, the card reappears in the deck, making it possible to draw the same card twice.

Every card that's not the Fool or the Jester comes back into the deck after you draw it, those two just disappear and don't come back.
